# How to use AWS amplify securely

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I'm experimenting with AWS amplify. In particular, looking to provide a means for a user to change their cognito password. I don't understand how that is done in a secure fashion given the client id is exposed.

What am I missing?

Here are the docs for what I'm using....

https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/tree/main/packages/amazon-cognito-identity-js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Amplify uses `amazon-cognito-identity-js` under the hood. So use Auth module from Amplify(`aws-amplify`).

```
import { Auth } from 'aws-amplify'
```

then you can let users change their password since they're already signed in and all necessary information is already in there(browser).

```
const currentUser = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();

const currentPassword = "";
const newPassword = "";

await Auth.changePassword(
  currentUser,
  currentPassword,
  newPassword
);
```

Comment: Thanks. I ended up doing the same thing but without using amplify. Instead I hit this endpoint described here (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_ChangePassword.html) which requires the access token. So this can be done securely. I'm not using amplify as (so far at least) I haven't needed it and didn't want the added dependencies.